# Is there a way to tell if a newline character is splitting two distinct words in Python?

Tags: python, newline

Using the below code, I imported a few .csv files with sentences like the following into Python:

```
df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f) for f in path), ignore_index=True)
```

Sample sentence:

```
I WANT TO UNDERSTAND WHERE TH\nERE ARE\nSOME \n NEW RESTAURANTS.      \n
```

While I have no problem removing the newline characters surrounded by spaces, in the middle of words, or at the end of the string, I don't know what to do with the newline characters separating words.

The output I want is as follows:

Goal sentence:

```
I WANT TO UNDERSTAND WHERE THERE ARE SOME NEW RESTAURANTS.
```

Is there a way for me to indicate in my code that the newline character is surrounded by two distinct words? Or is this classic garbage in, garbage out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some digging, I came up with two solutions.

**1. The [textwrap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html) package:** Though it seems that the textwrap package is normally used for visual formatting (i.e. telling a UI when to show "..." to signify a long string), it successfully identified the \n patterns I was having issues with. Though it's still necessary to remove extra whitespace of other kinds, this package got me 90% of the way there.

```
import textwrap
sample = 'I WANT TO UNDERSTAND WHERE TH\nERE ARE\nSOME \n NEW RESTAURANTS.      \n'
sample_wrap = textwrap.wrap(sample)
print(sample_wrap)
'I WANT TO UNDERSTAND WHERE THERE ARE SOME  NEW RESTAURANTS.      '
```

**2. Function to ID different \n appearance patterns:** The 'boil the ocean' solution I came up with before learning about textwrap, and it doesn't work as well. This function finds matches defined as a newline character surrounded by two word (alphanumeric) characters. For all matches, the function searches NLTK's words.words() list for each string surrounding the newline character. If at least one of the two strings is a word in that list, it's considered to be two separate words.

This doesn't take into consideration domain-specific words, which have to be added to the wordlist, or words like "about", which would be incorrectly categorized by this function if the newline character appeared as "ab\nout". I'd recommend textwrap for this reason, but still thought I'd share.

```
carriage = re.compile(r'(\n+)')
wordword = re.compile(r'((\w+)\n+(\w+))')
def carriage_return(sentence):
    if carriage.search(sentence):
        if not wordword.search(sentence):
            sentence = re.sub(carriage, '', sentence)
        else:
            matches = re.findall(wordword, sentence)
            for match in matches:
                word1 = match[1].lower()
                word2 = match[2].lower()
                if word1 in wordlist or word2 in wordlist or word1.isdigit() or word2.isdigit():
                    sentence = sentence.replace(match[0], word1 + ' ' + word2)
                else:
                    sentence = sentence.replace(match[0], word1+word2)
            sentence = re.sub(carriage, '', sentence)
    display(sentence)       
    return sentence
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df = df[~df['Sentence'].str.contains("\n")]
```

Comment: where ['Sentence'] can be replaced by whatever column name you have

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question - that only subsets my dataframe with rows where the 'Sentence' value does not include a newline.